# Open source Nodejs CMS for image/embed video sharing

Tags: node.js, content-management-system

I'm planning to learn about Nodejs and try to make a website for upload image or embed video from other site for my class.

It likes a public social network with just a just a few blog features for administrator only.

Cause of the limited of myself and the time, I decide to use an open source Nodejs CMS which has almost those function and contribute it to became my class's website.

Please give me some suggestion, are there any CMS like that?

Comment: I would say it's very easy to implement that in NodeJS, but you would have to add some HTML/JS on your front-end to help you. You can look for multer library if interested.

Comment: I know that have many library  javascript, css for back-end and front-end. But I have not used theme yet. With my limited time now, I think It would be better if I choose contribute to an existing CMS

Answer (score 1):

I tried once **Relax CMS**, it's really powerful.

From GitHub

> Relax is a powerful new generation CMS on top of React and Node.js which aims for a better way of building websites.
>   It features a live page builder based on components and a smart and easy way of binding dynamic data to them.

It's almost ready for production, but you can check the [demo](http://demo.getrelax.io/admin/login) out, and the project page https://github.com/relax/relax.

Comment: You can also check a staging deployment here http://staging.getrelax.io/admin

Credentials are the same  user: demo  pass: demo

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at Strapi (https://github.com/strapi/strapi)?

Halfway between a Node.js Framework and a Headless CMS, it saves weeks of API development time.

Thanks to its extensible plugin system, it provides a large set of built-in features:

- Extensible Admin Panel
- Authentication & Permissions management
- File management
- Content Management
- API Generator
- GraphQL support

Let me know if you have any question.